# How can I have a specific template on a extension

Tags: templates, joomla, accessibility

Hello I am sorry If this question has been already asked but I don't know how to search it. I have a problem with templates. I have a site (a normal with the default template and one accessibility with a special template). Now i have an extension (k2store) that i have in both templates. But if I click for an order in the url that loads  appears  the default template. Is there a way to make the k2store url that loads to display a specific menu depend on where I was? Please help any directions would be helpful

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you want to override the templates for k2Store, so I found this on a simple google search: [Overriding k2Store templates](http://k2store.org/support/documentation/item/45-howto-write-a-template-override.html)

Step 1: Create override structure in your template.
We can create template overirides for only those files and folders that reside in the views folder of a component (Example: components/com_k2store/views).

All the template overrides should reside inside the html folder of your template.

Let us say, your template's name is: YOUR_TEMPLATE

And you want to write overide for the files in the mycart view of K2Store component.

Then you should first go to

```
/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html
```

And create a folder named: com_k2store

Then go to

```
/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_k2store
```

and create folder called: mycart

Step 2: Copying files 
Now

Then you should copy the default.php from

```
/component/com_k2store/views/mycart/tmpl
```

to

```
/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_k2store/mycart
```

Step 3: Edit the files.
Now you can edit the default.php and carry out any changes. Like altering the scaffolding etc.